# Userform Combobox plays song in media player based on its value

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform, windows-media-player

Need help on this. I have combobox which links to sheet that will show default value based on Column A value. Example,

A| Twinkle Star | BY Ali

B| ABC Song     | By Kim

C| 123 Song     | By Els

If i choose A, in userform will shows the twinkle star and by ali in text box. 
I would like to set if A is chosen, it will play Twinkle Star song, when B is chosen, it wil play ABC Song. Need your opinion please.

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set xRg = Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2:C7")
    Me.ComboBox1.List = xRg.Columns(1).Value
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Me.TextBox1.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, xRg, 2, False)
    Me.TextBox2.Text = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox1.Value, xRg, 3, False)

    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
       Case "A"
            WindowsMediaPlayer1.Controls.Play= FollowHyperlink "#Sheet4!A2"
       Case "B"
            WindowsMediaPlayer1.Controls.Play= FollowHyperlink "#Sheet4!A3"
    End Select

End Sub
```

i tried using case a, b and links to hyperlink but not works.. 
appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a playlist, add a song to it and then play the song. Here is an exmaple

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim myPlayList As Object, myMedia As Object

    Dim wmP As WindowsMediaPlayer
    Set wmP = WindowsMediaPlayer2

    Dim MySong As String
    MySong = "C:\WhoLetTheDogsOut.mp3"

    With wmP
        Set myPlayList = .playlistCollection.newPlaylist("PersonalPlayList")

        .currentPlaylist = myPlayList

        Set myMedia = .mediaCollection.Add(MySong)

        .currentPlaylist.insertItem (.currentPlaylist.Count), myMedia
        .Controls.Play
    End With
End Sub
```

> thanks for your advice Siddarth.i tried your method but it will play the listed song But if i put a list there, when i change combobox value, the song will not change accordingly. – SES0204 16 mins ago

You need to stop the song, clear the playlist and recreate it to play. See the below example. I am using 2 different buttons to play the song. You can pass the value from the combobox to `Sub PlaySong(sng As String)`

```
Option Explicit

Dim myPlayList As Object, myMedia As Object
Dim wmP As WindowsMediaPlayer
Dim MySong As String

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set wmP = WindowsMediaPlayer2
End Sub

'~~> Play 1st Song
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MySong = "C:\WhoLetTheDogsOut.mp3"
    PlaySong MySong
End Sub

'~~> Play 2nd Song
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    MySong = "C:\Game Of Thrones.mp3"
    PlaySong MySong
End Sub

Private Sub PlaySong(sng As String)
    With wmP
        .Controls.stop
        .currentPlaylist.Clear
        Set myPlayList = .playlistCollection.newPlaylist("PersonalPlayList")
        .currentPlaylist = myPlayList
        Set myMedia = .mediaCollection.Add(sng)
        .currentPlaylist.insertItem (.currentPlaylist.Count), myMedia
        .Controls.Play
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your advice Siddarth.i tried your method but it will play the listed song But if i put a list there, when i change combobox value, the song will not change accordingly.

Comment: I have edited the aboev post. You may have to refresh it to see.

Comment: Hi Siddarth,Thanks a lot for your advice. Already manage to get solution as needed when i change the combobox to command box..